# Get first property key of JSON for a TreeView

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, treeview

Thanks for the answers on the previous two questions. I have a new one, and this one is a collapsible panel in jQuery. The concept is, the **first** key of a JSON object will appear as a button, and the other keys will be treated as regular text like `<p>` and the like.

I have this function which tests for the first index of an object.

```
function isFirstIndex(obj){
var key;
for(key in obj){
    if(obj[key]===0){
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I have tried this one:

```
function generateTree(data, selId){
var cnt = "";
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
        var row = data[i];
        $.each(row, function(key,value){
            if (isFirstIndex(row)){
                cnt += "<button>" + value + "</button><br/>";
            } else{
                cnt += "<strong>" + key + "</strong> :" + value + "<br/>";
            }

        });
        cnt += "<br/>";
     }

     $(selId).html(cnt);
}
```

But eventually found out in debugging that the `key` in the `isFirstIndex` function is compared with a string. 
Suppose I have a JSON :

```
{"userId" : 1, "name" : "cool name"}
```

I want to show the first key of any JSON set as a button, and the following properties will be ordinary text. Please allow me to post a `pseudo-code` like process.

```
Loop through all elements of data response
    Loop through each key and value of each data element.
        If the key is the first occurrence within the data set
            display it as a button.
        else
            display it as ordinary text.
    End Inner Loop
End outer loop
```

Comment: JSON is not ordered, so by doing it this way, you most probably will get weird behaviour across different browsers.

Comment: The order doesn't matter, I just want to know how to get the first key. @UtsavShah

Comment: Again, there is no guarantee at all that `"userId"` will be the first occurrence of your data set, as long as you use just an object. So your requirements "show userId as a button" and "if the key is the first occurrence within the data set, display it as a button" may not necessarily match.

Comment: I updated  the question once again.

Comment: If you are ready to accept **any** key to be first, hence to be a button (that is the "weird behaviour" mentioned by UtsavShah), then just use a flag to use a button first and ordinary text next. But be aware that different browsers may give different results (i.e. a different key being transformed as a button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What UtsavShah means is that `for (key in obj)` may iterate `keys` in `obj` in any order, JS spec does not enforce any order.

In fact, JS spec does not enforce any order not only for iteration, but **also for internal storage**: each JS engine implementation (hence depending on browsers) may store your JSON keys in any order, so even though you write your `"userId"` first, **it does not mean at all that the browser will keep it as the first key**. For that, you have to use an Array, or use a convention with a specific key.

The way your code is written, it will look for a key named "0" in your object (row). BTW your `i` iterator is useless in `isFirstIndex` function.

What you may try to achieve is to test if the value assigned to `"userId"` key is equal to 0? In that case, you would simply test `if (obj["userId"] === 0)`.

---

**EDIT:** (after you have explained that `userId` is the one to be a button)

If you just want the value in key `"userId"` to be displayed as a button, you would simply do:

```js
function generateTree(data, selId){
    var cnt = "";
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
        var row = data[i];
        $.each(row, function (key,value) { // Note that $.each does not necessarily iterates in any specific order either.
            if (key === "userId"){
                cnt += "<button>" + value + "</button><br/>";
            } else{
                cnt += "<strong>" + key + "</strong> :" + value + "<br/>";
            }

        });
        cnt += "<br/>";
     }

     $(selId).html(cnt);
}
```

---

**EDIT2:**

If you want an order, you need an array. If you want ordered keys, you could shape your data like so (of course this must be implemented in both server and client):

```
[
    {"userId": 1},
    {"name": "cool name"}
]
```

If you just need to know which particular key is specific and should be set as a button, make up a convention with your server and have your data specify which is the specific key, e.g.:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "cool name",
    "specificKeyToBeTransformedIntoAButton": "userId"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @ghybs . I have updated my code above with the code you have given. But still, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to achieve, which is not very clear from your question. I will edit the above answer to cover another case that may apply to you, but in the first place you should better explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have updated the question the best that I can. Thanks. @ghybs

Comment: That's because `userId` is the first occurrence in the set. However, I am working on a script that can handle any object returned in a response from server. What important to me is, I can only get the first property key within the JSON set.

Comment: Please read carefully: even if you receive `{"key0": "value0", "key1": "value1"}`, the JS engine may store `key0` and `key1` in any order it wishes. There is no "first key" in JS objects. You must use an array instead.

Comment: So you need to push every JSON contents in an array?

Comment: If you want an order, you need an array. If you just want a clue about something that must be a button, simply have your data specify which key is specific and should be a button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100337/discussion-between-cyval-and-ghybs).